# Google store says Ready to Publish

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play, ionic2

I'm trying to publish my ionic2 app on Google play.But still, I cannot do that.It doesn't show any errors.Can you tell me how to do this?

[image]

When I press the "Ready to Publish" button then it shows below screen.

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Op's feedback:**

Press `Mange Releases` Button -- > Then go to the bottom of the page --> Click `Review` Button.After that `Publish` button will be shown.

**Original Answer:**

It's similar to App store, Your application need to be accepted by tester for review and install on different device.
"Ready to publish" does not mean you can publish it globally unless you define internal or external (Alpha/Beta)tester, and those how choose to install your app need to review your app.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Good Luck

Comment: This is no longer correct. See the answer below regarding "Publishing overview"

Answer (score 62):

The accepted answer is now outdated.

1. On left side menu select 'Publishing overview'.
2. Click on 'Review and publish'.
3. Approve publish.

By the way, this is happening because **you've turned on 'Managed publishing status'**.
I recommend leaving it on, as it lets control when your app will actually be published after Google's review.

[image: Publishing overview page on Google Play Console]

Comment: Thank you. The new google play console design is rubbish, I literally spend minutes every time I need to interact with it, trying to find the button they've arbitrarily dumped into one of the release pages (but not others)

Comment: This one saved my time!!! Google should make it more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have been looking at "Ready for publishing" for a few days waiting for an auto-release or something as there is no release now button on that page showing tat particular status ....

Comment: Agreed, it's absolutely crazy that all of the pages that say "Ready for publishing" don't have an actual publish button. After browsing through the Releases overview and Production pages in an infinite loop, it finally took this answer to get me in the right place.

Comment: omg, I did a staggered layout for nothing... here i was thinking my app had 0 crashes.